# How run a method inside a wpf user control (something.xaml.cs) from another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Say you have a user control in which there is method which resets the form:

```
public void myReset()
{
   text1.Text="";
   text2.Text="";
}
```

And now I want to call this myReset() method from a method in a clsMyClass

```
    class clsMyclass
    {

        public clsMyClass()
        {
        }
        // ==================== Methods  =================
        public double SomeMethod(double Val)
        {
            UserControlRef.myReset();
            //Do things...
        }
   }
```

I don't know how to create a ref to the User Control. I have seen a code using Revit Extension works this way. I have done a lot of searches to figure this out but I couldn't find the right way.

Comment: This is actually very bad practise. According to Mvvm (which i am assuming you are working with) the model and the viewmodel may not know about the view. The code behind counts as a view in this case. There is some way to do this, by making it static, but then you will probably not be able to do anything with the view.

Comment: You will need to give us more information about the structure of your program, we can't know how your view and that Class is linked.

Comment: your usercontrol is a gui control that already exist in the MainWindows ??

Comment: @StijnvanGaal Take note of the `myReset()` method, specifically `...Text=""` -- that is to say, I don't think he's using MVVM.  However, it would behoove him to read up on the pattern, as I'd say he needs to readdress his whole design in this case.

Comment: @Ryan The program is actually a Revit Rex platform used to create Revit Extensions. The user controls are used in the final interface layouts.

Comment: The code it self uses the following method to create references to user controls to access the methods inside them:
`public override void OnCreateDialogs() 
        { 
            ...
 
            ParameterControlRef = new PyramidParametersControl(this); 
 
...
        }`

Comment: @Zwan Thanks for the comment and the answer. I actually need to set a value to an intelligent text box that can detect units and then read the value back from it. I want to  see if this will actually works. It would be ok if the user does not see the user control since it is actually only a dummy control just to do some work around.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the x:Name attribute in xaml: `x:Name="control"` This will give your instance a variable name. Then in code you can refer to the instance as the name you gave it. such as `control.myReset();`

Comment: Thanks but I cannot access control in another class.

Answer (score 1):

according with  @StijnvanGaal its not realy good methode anyway you can retrieve any UserControl and what is in. Here a sample
let say your usercontrol is in grid2 you can access it this way.

```
 int ChildNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grid2);
            for (int i = 0; i < ChildNumber; i++)
            {
                Control v = (Control)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grid2, i);

                if (v.GetType().ToString() == "Project_wpf.UserControlRef")
                {
                    UserControlRef CM = v as UserControlRef;
                    Console.WriteLine(CM.Name); //you can check his name here
                    CM.myReset();

                }
            }
```

basicaly this will active your MyReset() methode in all Usercontrole of type "Project_wpf.UserControlRef" who are child of Grid2